# How to force fail a CodeBuild (AWS)?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-codebuild

Just started with exploring AWS CodeBuild. How do I force fail a build in the install or pre_build phase if a mandatory custom environment variable (e.g. TARGET_ENVIRONMENT) is not set?

Comment: Have you tried `exit 1`?

Comment: `if [ -z "${TARGET_ENVIRONMENT}" ]; then
    exit 1;
fi`

Answer (score 8):

To fail a CodeBuild job, run any command which results in a non-zero exit status. You can check the existence of an environment variable using `[[ -z "${TARGET_ENVIRONMENT}" ]]`, which is true if the variable has length zero (ie is unset or set to the empty string, it's hard to tell the difference.  So the command:

`[[ -z "${TARGET_ENVIRONMENT}" ]] && exit 1`

Will return status 1, and should fail the job, if the `TARGET_ENVIRONMENT` variable does not have a value.